# How do I get an MS Access Combo Box to modify not just the Control Source field but another field

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a `city` table that has a `city_id`, `name`, `country_name` columns. This `country_name` column links with the `name` column in the `country` table.

The values I need to insert in my `company` table are the `city_id` and the `country_code` columns. The Combo box solves the insertion into the `city_id` column by just selecting the city's name. Nonetheless, I need to create a scenario where whenever a particular city is selected, the corresponding `country_name` where the city is located pops out in another combo box or something. (Dont forget, the cities already come with the `country_name` field listing the countries each city is located in).

It's also a possibility for me to edit the `city` table data source and substitute the list of countries in the `country_name` column for their actual country codes. This way I would be able to insert directly into the `country_code` column of the `company` table. The problem still remains how 2 columns from one Combo Box will be inserted into separate columns in the `company` table depending on which value is selected.

Thank you, I will be needing your support here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Column* property in the *AfterUpdate* event of the combobox, ie:

```
Me!OtherTextbox.Value = Me!YourComboBox.Column(1)
```